# Postgres Index Internals

Tags: database, postgresql

Example lets say, if we have a table with these data:

`outlet table 
id | name | location
01    w       KL
02    x       KL
03    y       KL
04    z       UK`

Assume we index this table by locate, will postgres create an index which has the key `KL` that refer to the 3 rows in the table ? Will be helpful if someone could refer any documentation or articles which talks about this, tried finding couldn't find any articles which says that will be the case.

Comment: About Btree index. Default index in Postgres. http://www.ovaistariq.net/733/understanding-btree-indexes-and-how-they-impact-performance/
Found with the first search in google about how Btree index works.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek but no where in the articles it says that a leaf nodes refers multiple rows.

Comment: Yes there is read it carefully "B+tree can have more than 1 keys in a node, in fact thousands of keys is seen typically stored in a node and hence, the branching factor of a B+tree is very large and that allows the B+trees to be a lot shallower as compared to their binary search tree counterparts."

Comment: The key here is actually the location itself i.e. KL, it doesn't say that the key stores references to multiple rows in the actual table.

Comment: Man, read the article pls - there is for example link to wikipedia page where you have information about how many keys can be in node and how many records. To be short yes in one node there can be relation to all of your 'KL' records.

Comment: The chapter ["Implementation"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-implementation.html) of the chapter "Chapter 63. B-Tree Indexes" of the manual, contains a reference to the README explaining the implementation details: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/backend/access/nbtree

Comment: Maybe you should read [a basic paper about B-Tree indexes](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/SS10/DBS-Intro/Reader/BayerBTree-72.pdf) by Bayer and MyCreight from 1972.